While upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS I got error for installing openmpi-bin
So, I was upgrading my PC to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS  and then I got error for installing openmpi-bin.
(base) anya@anya-dual:/etc/alternatives$ sudo apt install openmpi-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libcurl4t64 : Breaks: libcurl4 (< 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.3)
 libhdf5-openmpi-103-1 : Depends: libopenmpi3 (>= 4.1.0)
 libhdf5-openmpi-dev : Depends: libhdf5-openmpi-fortran-102 (= 1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2)
                       Depends: libhdf5-openmpi-cpp-103-1 (= 1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2)
                       Depends: libhdf5-openmpi-hl-cpp-100 (= 1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2)
                       Depends: libopenmpi-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libhdf5-openmpi-hl-fortran-100 : Depends: libhdf5-openmpi-fortran-102 (>= 1.10.2)
 openmpi-bin : Depends: libopenmpi3t64 (>= 4.1.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I did continue with sudo apt --fix-broken install
(base) anya@anya-dual:/etc/alternatives$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  acpi-support acpid aisleriot apturl apturl-common attr branding-ubuntu cheese cheese-common
  dctrl-tools dh-elpa-helper endeavour endeavour-common fonts-kacst fonts-kacst-one
  fonts-khmeros-core fonts-lao fonts-liberation2 fonts-lklug-sinhala fonts-sil-abyssinica
  fonts-sil-padauk fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-tibetan-machine fonts-tlwg-garuda fonts-tlwg-garuda-ttf
  fonts-tlwg-kinnari fonts-tlwg-kinnari-ttf fonts-tlwg-laksaman fonts-tlwg-laksaman-ttf
  fonts-tlwg-loma fonts-tlwg-loma-ttf fonts-tlwg-mono fonts-tlwg-mono-ttf fonts-tlwg-norasi
  fonts-tlwg-norasi-ttf fonts-tlwg-purisa fonts-tlwg-purisa-ttf fonts-tlwg-sawasdee
  fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf fonts-tlwg-typewriter fonts-tlwg-typewriter-ttf fonts-tlwg-typist
  fonts-tlwg-typist-ttf fonts-tlwg-typo fonts-tlwg-typo-ttf fonts-tlwg-umpush
  fonts-tlwg-umpush-ttf fonts-tlwg-waree fonts-tlwg-waree-ttf g++-11 gcc-12-base:i386 gedit
  gedit-common genisoimage gir1.2-amtk-5 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-goa-1.0
  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-300 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0
  gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-tepl-6 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
  gnome-bluetooth gnome-bluetooth-common gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines gnome-sudoku gnome-todo
  gnome-video-effects gsfonts gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
  guile-2.2-libs guile-3.0-libs i965-va-driver:i386 intel-media-va-driver:i386 irqbalance
  libabsl20210324 libaec-dev libamd2 libaom3:i386 libapparmor1:i386 libappstream4
  libasound2-plugins:i386 libasound2t64:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libatk1.0-data libatkmm-1.6-1v5
  libatomic1:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386
  libavcodec60:i386 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavutil58:i386 libblockdev-crypto2
  libblockdev-fs2 libblockdev-loop2 libblockdev-part-err2 libblockdev-part2 libblockdev-swap2
  libblockdev-utils2 libblockdev2 libboost-atomic1.74.0 libboost-chrono1.74.0t64
  libboost-date-time1.74.0 libboost-date-time1.83.0 libboost-dev libboost-filesystem1.74.0
  libboost-graph1.74.0 libboost-graph1.83.0 libboost-iostreams1.74.0 libboost-locale1.74.0
  libboost-program-options1.74.0 libboost-regex1.74.0 libboost-serialization1.74.0
  libboost-serialization1.83.0 libboost-system1.74.0 libboost-test1.74.0 libboost-thread1.74.0
  libbpf0 libbrotli1:i386 libbtf1 libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcairomm-1.0-1v5
  libcamd2 libcamel-1.2-63 libcbor0.8 libccolamd2 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcephfs2 libcheese-gtk25
  libcheese8 libcholmod3 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-3.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcodec2-1.2:i386 libcogl-common libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20
  libcogl20 libcolamd2 libcolord-gtk1t64 libcups2t64:i386 libcupsfilters1 libcurl4-openssl-dev
  libcxsparse3 libdatrie1:i386 libdav1d7:i386 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdazzle-common libdb5.3t64:i386
  libde265-0:i386 libdecor-0-0:i386 libdecor-0-plugin-1-cairo:i386 libdeflate0:i386
  libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdns-export1110 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdw1t64:i386 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20
  libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1
  libedataserver-1.2-26 libedataserverui-1.2-3 libedit2:i386 libelf1t64:i386 libevent-dev
  libevent-extra-2.1-7t64 libevent-openssl-2.1-7t64 libexif12:i386 libexpat1:i386
  libexporter-tiny-perl libflac12t64:i386 libflac8 libflac8:i386 libflann1.9 libfontconfig1:i386
  libfontembed1 libfreerdp-client2-2t64 libfreerdp-server2-2t64 libfreerdp2-2t64
  libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386 libgbm1:i386 libgc1 libgcab-1.0-0 libgd3:i386
  libgdbm-compat4t64:i386 libgdbm6t64:i386 libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:i386 libgedit-amtk-5-0
  libgedit-amtk-5-common libgedit-gtksourceview-300-0 libgedit-gtksourceview-300-common
  libgeocode-glib0 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0t64:i386 libglibmm-2.4-1t64 libglu1-mesa:i386
  libglvnd0:i386 libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libgnome-bluetooth13t64 libgnome-games-support-1-3
  libgnome-games-support-common libgnome-todo libgnutls30t64:i386 libgoa-backend-1.0-1
  libgomp1:i386 libgoogle-glog0v5 libgphoto2-port12t64:i386 libgpm2:i386 libgraphblas6
  libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssdp-1.2-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386
  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgtkmm-3.0-1t64 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-common
  libgupnp-1.2-1 libgweather-3-16 libgweather-common libharfbuzz0b:i386
  libheif-plugin-aomdec:i386 libheif-plugin-aomenc:i386 libheif-plugin-libde265:i386
  libheif1:i386 libheimbase1t64-heimdal libheimbase1t64-heimdal:i386 libhogweed6t64:i386
  libhwloc-dev libibverbs-dev libicu70 libicu70:i386 libicu74:i386 libieee1284-3t64:i386
  libigdgmm12:i386 libilmbase25 libio-prompt-tiny-perl libisc-export1105 libjack-jackd2-0:i386
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg-turbo8-dev
  libjpeg8:i386 libjpeg8-dev libjs-jquery-ui libklu1 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.5-0
  libldap-2.5-0:i386 libldl2 liblist-moreutils-perl liblist-moreutils-xs-perl libllvm15t64
  libllvm15t64:i386 libllvm17t64:i386 libltdl7:i386 liblz4-dev libmagickcore-6.q16-6
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libmessaging-menu0 libmongoose2
  libmozjs-91-0 libmp3lame0:i386 libmpdec3 libmpfr-dev libmpg123-0t64:i386
  libnautilus-extension1a libncurses6:i386 libnet-ip-perl libnetpbm10 libnetplan0
  libnettle8t64:i386 libnfs13 libnghttp2-14:i386 libnl-3-dev libnl-route-3-dev libnsl-dev
  libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386 libnuma-dev libnuma1:i386 libodbc2 libodbc2:i386 libodbccr2
  libodbccr2:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386 libopenexr25 libopengl0:i386 libopenjp2-7:i386
  libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0t64:i386 liborcus-0.17-0 liborcus-parser-0.17-0 libosmesa6
  libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386
  libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libparted-fs-resize0t64 libpcap0.8t64:i386
  libpci3:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre3 libperl5.34 libperl5.34:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386
  libplist3 libpng16-16t64:i386 libpoppler118 libpoppler118:i386 libpostproc55 libprotobuf23
  libpsl5t64:i386 libpulse0:i386 libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev libpython3.10-minimal
  libpython3.10-stdlib libqpdf28 libqqwing2v5 libqt5svg5-dev librados2 libraw20 librbio2
  libreoffice-pdfimport librest-0.7-0 libroken18-heimdal libroken18-heimdal:i386 librsvg2-2:i386
  librsvg2-common:i386 librtmp1:i386 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2
  librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libsamplerate0:i386 libsasl2-2:i386
  libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsensors5:i386
  libsharpyuv0:i386 libshine3:i386 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libsigsegv2 libsliplu1 libsmbios-c2
  libsnapd-glib1 libsnappy1v5:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio7.0:i386 libsoup-gnome-2.4-1
  libsoxr0:i386 libspeex1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libspqr2 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssh-4:i386
  libssl-dev libstdc++-11-dev libstdc++6:i386 libsuitesparseconfig5 libsvtav1enc1d1:i386
  libswresample4:i386 libswscale5 libtasn1-6:i386 libtbb-dev libtbb12 libtbbbind-2-5
  libtbbmalloc2 libtepl-6-4 libtepl-common libthai0:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5 libtiff5:i386
  libtiff6:i386 libtirpc-dev libtwolame0:i386 libumfpack5 libunistring2 libunistring2:i386
  libunwind8:i386 liburing2 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libutf8proc2 libv4l-0t64:i386
  libv4lconvert0t64:i386 libva-drm2:i386 libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386 libvdpau1:i386
  libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvkd3d-shader1 libvkd3d-shader1:i386 libvkd3d1 libvkd3d1:i386
  libvncserver1 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx9:i386 libvulkan1:i386
  libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebp7:i386
  libwebpmux3:i386 libwinpr2-2t64 libwrap0:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-164:i386
  libx265-199:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386
  libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386
  libxcursor1:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386
  libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxss1:i386
  libxvidcore4:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzvbi0t64:i386 linux-headers-5.15.0-121
  linux-headers-5.15.0-121-generic linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40 linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-40
  linux-image-5.15.0-121-generic linux-image-6.5.0-45-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-121-generic
  linux-modules-6.5.0-45-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-121-generic
  linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-45-generic mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386
  mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 nautilus-share ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 openmpi-common
  perl-modules-5.34 python3-blessings python3-future python3-lib2to3 python3-lockfile
  python3-macaroonbakery python3-protobuf python3-pyatspi python3-pymacaroons python3-rfc3339
  python3.10 python3.10-dev python3.10-minimal samba samba-ad-provision samba-vfs-modules
  tdb-tools ubuntu-advantage-tools va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386 vkd3d-compiler
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libhdf5-openmpi-103-1t64 libhdf5-openmpi-fortran-102t64 libhdf5-openmpi-hl-100t64 libmunge2
  libopenmpi3t64 libpmix2t64
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libcurl4 libhdf5-openmpi-103-1 libhdf5-openmpi-dev libhdf5-openmpi-hl-100
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libhdf5-openmpi-103-1t64 libhdf5-openmpi-fortran-102t64 libhdf5-openmpi-hl-100t64 libmunge2
  libopenmpi3t64 libpmix2t64
0 to upgrade, 6 to newly install, 4 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,742 kB of archives.
After this operation, 569 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 560460 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libhdf5-openmpi-dev (1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mpi
dpkg: error processing package libhdf5-openmpi-dev (--remove):
 installed libhdf5-openmpi-dev package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/h5pcc.openmpi to provide /usr/bin/h5pcc (h5pcc) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/hdf5-openmpi.pc to provide /usr/lib
/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/hdf5.pc (hdf5.pc) in auto mode
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mpi
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed libhdf5-openmpi-dev package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit sta
tus 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libhdf5-openmpi-dev
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

But that didn't get me anywhere. Just FYI before I have already tried Stackoverflow advices like this but my error is different. Also, because in /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/ I don't have any file mpi.
So, I am kind of lost what to do next... Thank you for any advice!
I have tried Googling similar issue, sudo apt --fix-broken install and some other suggested solutions, but it didn't help me.
Edit:
(base) anya@anya-dual:~$ apt policy libhdf5-openmpi-dev
libhdf5-openmpi-dev:
  Installed: 1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.10.10+repack-3.1ubuntu4
  Version table:
     1.10.10+repack-3.1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status```


Please [edit] your question to include the output of apt policy libhdf5-openmpi-dev - based on the package version 1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2 it looks like you have some old (22.04 or 22.10) sources

@steeldriver I have added the output, but I am still not sure what to do next etc.

So I was following this: https://superuser.com/a/1802869

Copy folder /etc/apt just to be sure: sudo cp -a /etc/apt /var/tmp/apt-bkp-2024-09-16-mid-upgrade
rename sources.list.distUpgrade to sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt autoremove

(base) anya@anya-dual:/$ sudo apt autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.  libcurl4t64 : Breaks: libcurl4 (< 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.3)  libhdf5-openmpi-103-1 : Depends: libopenmpi3 (>= 4.1.0) but it is not installed  libhdf5-openmpi-dev : Depends: libhdf5-openmpi-fortran-102 
    1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2) but it is not installed
Depends: libhdf5-openmpi-cpp-103-1  1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2) but it is not installed
Depends: libhdf5-openmpi-hl-cpp-100  1.10.7+repack-4ubuntu2) but it is not installed
Depends: libopenmpi-dev but it is not installed  libhdf5-openmpi-hl-fortran-100 : Depends: libhdf5-openmpi-fortran-102 (>= 1.10.2) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


Uninstall and install again mpi: dpkg -l | grep mpi.
In my case it looked like that the mpi is already partially uninstalled, so I have tried sudo apt --fix-broken install.
Just finish with sudo apt autoremove

